# Cant make a fetch post request from front end client to local node server, only GET requests work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, fetch

When making a post request to my local server (localhost:8080/page) i am shown 'Cannot GET /page'. I am [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avz79.png)using Google Chrome where the dev tools network tab shows:

Here is my front end code with the simple fetch statement:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'
import OAuth from './OAuth'
import Loading from './Loading'
import Footer from './Footer'
import Tweets from './Tweets'
import { API_URL } from './config'
import './App.css'
const socket = io(API_URL) //,{transports: ['websocket']}
const providers = ['twitter', 'google', 'facebook', 'github']//import theese in because our auth controller needs to call our event for each provider which the event is named after the provider

export default class App extends Component {

  state = {
    loading: true
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    socket.on('connect', function(){
      console.log('connected')
    });

    fetch(`${API_URL}/wake-up`)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.ok) {
          this.setState({loading: false})
        }
      })

      const data = {
        random1: 'random',
        random2: 'random-input'
      }

      const options = {
          method:'POST',
          mode: 'cors',
          header: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }

        fetch(`${API_URL}/page`, options);
  }

  render() {
    const divStyles = {

    }
    const buttons = (providers, socket) =>
      providers.map(provider =>
        <OAuth
          provider={provider}
          key={provider}
          socket={socket}
        />
      )

    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <div className='container'>
          {this.state.loading
            ? <Loading />
            : buttons(providers, socket)
          }
        </div>
{
buttons
? <Tweets provider='twitter' />
: <div> Hasnt fetched</div>
}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is my backend node server (server.js) where i have app.post available but still no results and ive attached my routes file below that:

```
        require('dotenv').config()
    const express = require('express')
    const path = require('path')
    const fs = require('fs')
    const https = require('https')
    const http = require('http')
    const passport = require('passport')
    const session = require('express-session')
    const cors = require('cors')
    const socketio = require('socket.io')
    const authRouter = require('./lib/auth.router')
    const passportInit = require('./lib/passport.init')
    const { SESSION_SECRET, CLIENT_ORIGIN } = require('./config')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const app = express()
    let server


    // If we are in production we are already running in https
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      server = http.createServer(app)
    }
    // We are not in production so load up our certificates to be able to
    // run the server in https mode locally
    else {
      const certOptions = {
        key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./certs/server.key')),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('./certs/server.crt'))
      }
      server = https.createServer(certOptions, app)
    }

    // Setup for passport and to accept JSON objects


    app.use(express.json())
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    passportInit()

    // Accept requests from our client
    app.use(cors())

    // saveUninitialized: true allows us to attach the socket id to the session
    // before we have athenticated the user
    app.use(session({
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true
    }))

    // Connecting sockets to the server and adding them to the request
    // so that we can access them later in the controller
    const io = socketio(server)
    app.set('io', io)

    // Catch a start up request so that a sleepy Heroku instance can
    // be responsive as soon as possible

    app.get('/wake-up', (req, res) => res.send('')) 
      app.post('/page', (req, res)=>{
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('yes');
})
    // Direct other requests to the auth router
    app.use('/', authRouter)




    server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => { //calllback function
      console.log('listening...')
    })
```

Route file auth.router.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
const passport = require('passport')
const authController = require('./auth.controller')

// Setting up the passport middleware for each of the OAuth providers
const twitterAuth = passport.authenticate('twitter')
const googleAuth = passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile'] })
const facebookAuth = passport.authenticate('facebook')
const githubAuth = passport.authenticate('github')

// Routes that are triggered by the callbacks from each OAuth provider once
// the user has authenticated successfully


router.get('/twitter/callback', twitterAuth, authController.twitter)//on callback we are authenticating twitter and then sending our data/user info to the io to be called up on client via the socket.io (socket.on())
router.get('/google/callback', googleAuth, authController.google)
router.get('/facebook/callback', facebookAuth, authController.facebook)
router.get('/github/callback', githubAuth, authController.github)

// This custom middleware allows us to attach the socket id to the session
// With that socket id we can send back the right user info to the right
// socket
router.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.session.socketId = req.query.socketId
  next()
})

// Routes that are triggered on the client ////so may not need certain code from the twitter developer page
router.get('/twitter', twitterAuth)
router.get('/google', googleAuth)
router.get('/facebook', facebookAuth)
router.get('/github', githubAuth)


module.exports = router
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You define a post route, but you're `get`-ing the page, looking at your dev-tools screenshot

Comment: Yes thanks, I realised but I was not sure how to change from a get to a post. As I want data posted to that /page route

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your route for both get and post if you want to be able to reach it with both verbs. You could do something like this:

```
const handler = (req, res)=> {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send('yes');
};
app.get('/page', handler);
app.post('/page', handler);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked but id also like to be able to post the data sent from the fetch post request within app.js. Could you possibly help some more?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you want to do exactly.

Comment: I am trying to return the post request, ive realised the only method being listened for is the get request, but the post request does not seem to work.